# Can I force clients of my phone's Wi-Fi hotspot to use my DNS?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, dns, 8.1-oreo

My phone is a Mi A1 with Oreo 8.1. It is not rooted.

I am offering WiFi using hotpsot .

I discovered that devices connected to my hotspot do not inherit the DNS server from my hotspot.

Questions: *is there a way to push DNS to clients connected to my hotspot?*

I have two custom DNS, self made, with public IP. And I would like that people using my wifi could use these DNS.

Comment: I modified my question to remove all references to vpn at all. The question is not how to share vpn but how to force the use of my device's DNS servers. Sorry if too much context has dirocted away from main problem

Comment: I don't have a problem with them in general. In some contexts, they can be concise and simple to understand. It's just not the style on most SE sites, because the site automatically adds your first one or two tags to the page title anyway.

Comment: Since you were earlier talking of VPN , [this app](https://www.xda-developers.com/vpn-hotspot-share-vpn-connection/) may be of interest to you. Not tested by me

Comment: Well. I asked for a way to force use of my DNS. This app do not do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Each connecting client identifies using its own IP address BEFORE being granted internet access, This means that it does not need to clone address or servers after connection, it can continue sending and receiving packets along its establish (independent) route, identifying as it's own device.